# Keeping a TileService active?

Tags: android, service, android-7.0-nougat

I have a Tile that, when active, runs a timer, performs a task for those five minutes, and then goes back to it's inactive state after a certain amount of time.

The problem I'm running into however is the service getting killed. I'm already calling `startForeground(id)` when said timer starts, but my service still gets killed nonetheless. I'm also returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand(intent, flags, startID)`.

Is there anyway to absolutely prevent it from being killed, or am I just out of luck here?

Comment: I suspect strongly that a `TileService` is not started, but rather bound to. If so, since `startService()` is not called on it, the service will be destroyed when the client unbinds. I suggest that you move your business logic to a separate ordinary `Service`, so you can better control its lifetime.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, I think you're on to something here. I'll try that, and get back to you on that!

Comment: @CommonsWare Just wanted to get back to you and let you know that it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using @CommonWare's advice. I abstracted all of my logic to a regular `Service` class, and am calling `startService()` from my Tile's service class.

The one road bump I ran into was figuring out how to get the Tile instance to the new Service (which handles updating the tile's text and state), but solved this by using an `Application` class to hold a reference to the Tile. (`TileService` updates this reference every onClick, before calling `startService()`)

It's probably not the cleanest and best way to do it, but it's the way that I'm choosing to roll with for now.

Comment: [`Tile` is `Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/Tile.html) and could be passed via an `Intent` extra to the other service.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with passing it through the Intent. I've opened an issue on the bug tracker (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216639), in case I'm not just doing it wrong :)